# The result returned by Google Assistant is the result of google home, not the result of the uploaded custom device action

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I used the gRPC API to call google-assistant-sdk and uploaded Custom device actions. Before Friday, the google assistant returned the semantics is normal, but now, it works as follows:

"turn on the TV"

"I don't see any remote devices linked to your account. You can add devices in the Google Home app."

How can I get it to return semantics?

Comment: Seems like the test draft you have expired. If you run gactions again to put the project in test mode, it should become active again

Comment: I have tried running gactions, but as long as there is such a device in the google home app, it overrides the result of the Custom Device Actions.
When I delete the device on google home, it can successfully return to the Actions. But Google Home seems to have a default device TV, although I don't have a TV.

Comment: I mean is If I upload the device model and device instance, it will be displayed in the google assistant's Home Control, virtual and other devices.
the Home Control priority seems to be higher than Custom Devices Actions @NickFelker

Comment: Custom actions are higher priority than home control. Does your action trigger if you add one for a random thing like "turn on the coffee"?

Comment: I added something like "Light/TV/Floor lamp" to the Custom Actions.And It worked fine in the past.But since last Friday,I said "turn on the TV/light",the Actions will not trigger,it returns the result of the Home Control.If I said anything is not in the Home Control,like "turn on the floor lamp",the Actions trigger.I am trying to run Gactions again and it doesn't work.I tried to create a new google account for testing,the Home Control without a device,every word can be, except for "turn on the TV".I just tried what you said,the Actions trigger,so are there some bugs in assistant?@NickFelker